# Using Residue Theorem/Laurent Series to evaluate $\int_{c}$ $\frac{z^m}{2-\frac{1}{Z}} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $m$ be an integer and $C$ be the circle $C(0; 1)$ traversed in the counterclockwise direction.

What is the value of $\int_{c}$ $\frac{z^m}{2-\frac{1}{Z}} dz$

a) when $m\ge-1$?

b) when $m<-1$?

I have tried solving for (a) and here is my working:

Using residue theorem and laurent series expansion, the integral equals to

$2\pi i\times[\text{Res}(\frac{z^m}{2-\frac{1}{Z}};0) + \text{Res}(\frac{z^m}{2-\frac{1}{Z}};\frac{1}{2})]$

I am not sure if this is correct, but I evaluated it as 2$\pi i$ eventually.

Any idea of how to solve the second part? Is is an essential singularity?

Comment: where are the poles and singularities ? $\frac{z^m}{2 - 1/z} = \frac{z^{m+1}}{2z - 1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be written as

$$f(z):=\frac{z^{m+1}}{2z-1}=\frac12\;\frac{z^{m+1}}{z-\frac12}$$

Thus, $\;m+1\ge0\iff m\ge-1\;$ and there's a simple pole at $\;z=\frac12\;$. When $\;m+1<0\iff m<-1\;$ there's *an additional* pole at $\;z=0\;$ of order $\;m+1\;$ (assuming $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ all the time).

In the first case you need

$$\text{Res}_{z=\frac12}(f)=\lim_{z\to\frac12}\,\frac12\; z^{m+1}=\frac1{2^{m+2}}$$

In the second you also need the residue at zero:

$$\lim_{z\to0}\;z^{-(m+1)}\,(f(z))^{(m)}=\lim_{z\to0}\left(\frac12\;\frac1{z-\frac12}\right)^{(m)}=\ldots$$

Comment: thanks for answering! However, I dont quite understand the part b answer. how do you differentiate m times while taking limit?

Comment: @Bread Try to differentiate a few times to see the pattern, which is pretty simple:$$\left(\frac1{z-\frac12}\right)'=-\frac1{\left(z-\frac12\right)^2}\;,\; \;\left(\frac1{z-\frac12}\right)''=\frac2{\left(z-\frac12\right)^3}\;,\; \;\left(\frac1{z-\frac12}\right)'''=-\frac{3!}{\left(z-\frac12\right)^4}\ldots$$

Comment: oh okay, thanks!